# How to fire a query with a number of variables from local array

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry if title is not properly set. 
The problem is I want to filter DataFrame by comparing df's column with a couple of values from an array:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
array = np.arange(10)
#simple query
df.query('A == %d' %array[3])
```

Above query runs perfectly fine, the below query also runs without issue:

```
df.query('A == [3,4,5]')
```

Logically, below code should work too, because I select values from 3rd to 5-th from `array`:

```
df.query('A == %d' %array[3:5])
```

Nevertheless, it gives me an error:

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not numpy.ndarray
```

Kindly suggest the path I should follow.
Thank you!

Comment: Does it have to be a query operation or is this valid as well - `df[df['A'].isin([1, 2, 3])]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns an integer, accepted by the `%d` format

```
df.query('A == %d' %array[3])
```

This returns an array, not the same object!, refused by the latter

```
df.query('A == [%s]' %array[3:5])
```

I suggest:

```
df.query('A == [%s]' % ",".join([str(a) for a in array[3:6]]))
```

this will send `'A == [3,4,5]'` to the query

Comment: This worked brilliantly! And thank you for thorough explanation.

Answer (score 2):

`numexpr` doesn't support slicing so the closest you can get is to create a variable with the required data, then reference it from the query (note that the slicing here creates a view of the original `array` and doesn't perform a copy):

```
sliced = array[3:6]
df.query('A == @sliced')
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, sadly but solution gives an error:
`ValueError: Lengths must match to compare`